# How to retrieve the Sign In authentication result from WebHook Client?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm setting up a Dialogflow fulfillment that saves user data after he logs in.

I'm using an example from the inline editor (code below):

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I also wanted to use account linking, so I've added a new function like this:

```
function signIn(agent) {
  agent.conv().ask(new SignIn('Log in to link accounts'));
}

intentMap.set('Sign In', signIn);
```

So far so good, the user is asked if he wants to create account and all of that. The problem is... the next step should be to check, if user did actually sign in. In this example they are using a whole different approach for handling fulfillments (at least that's what I think):

https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-google-sign-in-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js

```
app.intent('Get Sign In', async (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
    return conv.close(`Let's try again next time.`);
  }
  //more code
});
```

...and now I'm in trouble, 'cause I only have `request` and `response` arguments, that are combined into an `agent` WebhookClient object that's passed to the function. I don't have the `signin` argument and I don't know where to find the information. I've checked so many different properties within the agent and the data is nowhere to be found...

So, my question is either:

- does anyone know if the information is stored somewhere in the request/response/agent objects? Or maybe it "could" be stored, but I have to change/add something to the Intent definition in Dialogflow console (I'm not showing you the definition here, because it's almost empty, I've enabled webhooks and added a "Sign In" event as a trigger, and the fulfillment function executes after user account creation, so it's OK - but it just doesn't have the `signin` argument),
- if it is not stored there and I cannot handle the SignIn using WebhookClient - can you please explain how can I "merge" those two approaches? Or do I have to write the code exactly as they did in the example and abandon WebhookClient once and for all? I really wouldn't want to do that, though, I would have to rewrite many lines of code... :(

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to do this with Actions on Google Account Linking? Are you doing it using Google Sign-In or through OAuth?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, it's invoking Google Action. I chose only to use Google Sign-In.